# exactly one root of the equation $e^{a}x^2-e^{2a}x+e-1=0$ lie between $1$ and $2$ are given as

Tags: calculus

> The values of $a$ for which exactly one root of the equation $e^{a}x^2-e^{2a}x+e-1=0$ lie between
>
> $1$ and $2$ are given as

Try: Let $f(x) = e^{a}x^2-e^{2a}x+e-1,$ where $e^{a}=k>0$

So $f(x)=kx^2-k^2x+e-1\;, k>0$ Represent upward parabola

If exactly one root lie between $1$ and $2,$ Then $f(1)\cdot f(2)<0$

So $(k-k^2+e-1)\cdot (4k-2k^2+e-1)<0$

could someone help me how i solve it, Thanks

Comment: Nitpicking:  One root between $1$ and $2$ might also mean that the second root is at $1$ or $2$

Comment: [solve $(k−k^2+e−1)⋅(4k−2k^2+e−1)<0$ for $k$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(k%E2%88%92k%5E2%2Be%E2%88%921)%E2%8B%85(4k%E2%88%922k%5E2%2Be%E2%88%921)%3C0+for+k), done!

Comment: [The exact (closed form) bounds for $a$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(e%5Ek%E2%88%92e%5E(2k)%2Be%E2%88%921)%E2%8B%85(4e%5Ek%E2%88%922e%5E(2k)%2Be%E2%88%921)%3C0+for+k)

Comment: What about multiplicity? How many root has the function $(x-1.5)^2$ between $1$ and $2$?